# proof of uniform hypersphere sampling

Tags: gaussian-noise

In this [paper](http://compneuro.uwaterloo.ca/files/publications/voelker.2017.pdf),
they shortly introduced how to uniformly sample points from the n-sphere.

The points of n-sphere consist with normal variables.
My question is ..

1. If I samlpe coefficients of ring using normal distribution,
   what is differences between sphere sample and normal sample of ring?
2. How normal variables make uniform distribution in sphere? Can I formally prove it?
3. If Q2 is possible, is it also possible in cube?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Per you comment, if we sample coordinates from a finite ring, the probability distribution function will have to be discreet and so the closest that we can hope for is a discretised normal distribution. A discrete distribution will not be uniform over a continuous space (and also the lengths of the vectors will mean they of not lie on the same sphere unless projected). If $q$ tends to infinity, the variance of the discretised normal is allowed to grow and we normalise lengths, then the distribution will tend to uniform.
2. We prove the general case of the $n$-sphere. We note that the probability density function of an $n$-fold Gaussian distribution is given by
   $$\frac1{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp(-x_1^2/2)\exp(-x_2^2/2)\cdots\exp(-x_n^2/2)=\frac1{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots +x_n^2)\right).$$
   Converting to [spherical polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) then gives the density function
   $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-r^2\right)$$
   which is independent of all of the angular variables and so is uniform on spheres. Rescaling by the radius $r$ therefore gives a variable uniform on the $n$-sphere.
3. No, the density function in this case is no independent of the angular components. However, by sampling components uniformly you can sample uniformly from the $n$-cube. By either rescaling or selecting a face at random and then selecting a point on the $(n-1)$-cube, you can sample uniformly form the surface of the $n$-cube.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In first question, the ring is R=Zq[x]/(x^n+1) for n=2^k. I considered the ring that is commonly used in cryptography.

Let a={a_0, ... ,a_(n-1)} is a component of R. We pick a_i from normal distribution N(0,1).
And s={x_0, ... ,x_(n-1)} is a point of n-sphere that the distribution of each x_i is normal distribution N(0,1).
In this case, from the perspective of vectors, a and s have same distribution?

Or, for A=(a_1,a_2, ... , a_t) = component of R^t, A and s have same distribution?